# Asana : How can i relate Followers, Assignee and Users/Groups

Tags: task, asana

By using asana api, i can see assignee and followers have same id (as they are same user) but does it really differs if i consider assigneeId and followerID.
Can i club assignee, followers and users/groups into one? Please suggest..

Comment: Can you clarify the question? As you ascertained, users have the same ID whether they are followers or assignees. However, each task has only one assignee (or none), but can have as many followers as you like, so the fields do have different meaning.

Comment: Can i save same users as followers/assignee/users under same id?

For exp: 

1 task is having assignee "UserA(assigneeid = 123)"
and followers as "UserA(followerid = 123)", "UserB(followerid = 120)"

so My question is this user same which is added as followers and assignee (UserA)?

Can i store user information in one table and relate the follower and assignee as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all assignees and followers are User objects, so the same ID represents the same User in all cases. Additionally, it's worth noting that every ID for objects in Asana is unique. That means that if there's a User with ID 12345, then the *only* object in Asana with the ID 12345 is that user. So if you have an ID, regardless of context you can be sure it is the exact same object if it has the same ID.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! :)